# React router v4, cannot find in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to use react router v4. The version I'm using is 4.1.1. When the page loads It renders the Home component as it should. But if I navigate to `localhost:8080/about` or `localhost:8080/test2`, I get this in the browser

```
Cannot GET /about
```

My `App.jsx` file:

```
import React  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from '../components/Home.jsx';
import Test from '../components/Test.jsx';

const Test2 = () => (
  <div>test2 component</div>
);

const App = (props) => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={Test} />
      <Route path="/test2" render={Test2} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
export default App;
```

Webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './client/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './client/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/'},
      { test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: '/node_modules/'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
};
```

Comment: the problem lies with your server. Are you using `webpack-dev-server` or someother one. Show the related config.

Comment: Yes I have edited and included my webpack. Yes im using webpack-dev-server

Comment: There is no mention of `webpack-dev-server` can you show your package.json of how you start your dev server ?

Comment: @Panther  


   "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server"
      },

Comment: change your `start` in `package.json` to `webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback` and then start the server again.

Comment: Thanks, look at my edit. I added the devServer, and now I dont need --history-api-fallback in my package.json start script

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `output.publicPath = '/'` to your config. Here's an example webpack config below which uses ^ and fixes the refresh issue for me. If you're curious "why", [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually) will help.

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```